# Find $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $12m=10 \pmod {80}$ (without a calculator).

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have the following question :

> Find $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $12m=10\pmod {80}$.

The answer is that such an $m$ does not exist.

> How could one conclude that without a calculator?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note $$12m \equiv 10 \pmod{80} \implies 12m \equiv 10 \pmod{4}$$
Now
$$12m \equiv 0 \pmod 4 $$
However $$10 \equiv 2 \not \equiv 0 \pmod 4$$
So no such $m \in \mathbb{N}$ exists.

Comment: Why is this correct? $12m \equiv 10 \pmod{80} \implies 12m \equiv 10 \pmod{4}$

Comment: Because $12m \equiv 10 \pmod {80}$ implies that $12m-10=80k$ for some integer $k$. $12m-10=80k=4(20k)$, so $12m \equiv 10 \pmod {4}$.

Comment: @JaVaPG Sorry, forgot to ping you. See my earlier comment.

Comment: Sorry took me some time to understand now I get it, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The condition $12m\equiv 10\pmod{80}$ is equivalent to $6m\equiv5\pmod{40}$, which cannot be satisfied because, for any $m,k\in\mathbb{Z}$, the integers $6m-5$ and $40k$ are respectively odd and even.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose such an $m\in\mathbb{N}$ does exist.

We now have $12m\equiv10 \pmod{80}$, so write $12m-10$ as a multiple of $80$; thus $12m-10=80$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Now $12m-10=4\ell$ for $\ell=40k$, so that $$12m\equiv10\pmod{4}.\tag{1}$$

But then
$$\begin{align}
0&\equiv12m\pmod{4} \\
&\stackrel{(1)}{\equiv}10 \pmod{4} \\
&\equiv2 \pmod{4},
\end{align}$$ a contradiction.

Thus no such $m$ exists.